# Performance wise Best way to send xml data to php file in c#

Tags: c#, php, xml

i have a XML file and i want it to send php page to write it into mysql database.

for a example,
I have a class called `data` which has few attributes. then these object values saved in local cache as a xml file as follows:

```
<data>
   <value1></value1>
   <value2></value2>
   ..........
</data>
```

so i want to send these data to mysql database. 
my server side use php and i'm new to php. 
so what is the best way to send these data.

1. send these values as parameters by access object of data (c#)

> string data = "&value1=" + d.value1+"&value2="+ d.value2 ........;

2.
 send xml file directly to php page and, in php file read xml file and get required data

what is the best way to send those data? (performance wise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is likely to be 'it depends'.

1. How complex is your XML structure and how easy it is to parse it on the server-side (PHP)? If the XML itself is relatively simple and the number of parameters is unlikely to increase dramatically, you may consider sending them as part of URL. However, if the XML is going to change and become more complex, you may end up continuously inventing bicycles of converting XML into URL parameters with such an approach.
2. Sending XML directly to the server-side may be easier because you don't need to convert XML to URL parameters. Furthermore, you don't need to care how large is your XML, whereas with URL query parameters you need - the URL shall be no longer than [2083 symbols](http://www.google.com/search?q=URL%202083%20symbol&oq=URL%202083%20symbol&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Also, if you use the URL parameters approach, be careful about string concatenation - you need to escape values of your data, e.g.  using the [Uri.EscapeDataString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx) method.

Performance-wise, there are three aspects to consider:

1. If there are not too much of URI escaping and parameters have fairly trivial values (i.e. mostly numbers/ASCII characters), parameters are likely to be transferred faster due to usage of HTTP GET rather than HTTP POST and lesser amount of data to transfer. However, transfer gains will be offset by the cost of conversion of XML to parameters, though it would be negligible for a small XML.
2. If XML is complex in structure and the values in data are of arbitrary length, then its conversion to URL parameters may prove to be inefficient and even impossible in some cases. If you end up using HTTP POST rather than HTTP GET, it is highly doubtful that conversion to parameters would make any sense at all.
3. Parsing of XML at the server-side is likely to be slower than parsing of URL parameters. However, this is questionable and needs proper measurement.

Finally, it might be recommended to think about -- why is such low-level aspect of performance interests you at this point in development? Do you have some performance issues and found out that the bottleneck is in that little detail? See [an excellent article about performance by Eric Lippert here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/10/17/53237.aspx). You might be better off going ahead with the most straightforward solution (i.e. easiest to code and maintain) and measure the performance issues later on.